# Cast [regex] in PowerShell results in case sensitivity strangeness - why?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell scripting, and I am puzzled by some behaviour I have encountered.

I have been following examples to learn how to use matching and had seen some examples where [regex] was put in front of a string. I had assumed (perhaps wrongly) that this is a cast, explicitly specifying that the object is a regular expression. But it seems that using [regex] changes the case sensitivity of the resulting match:

```
PS > $array = 'ABC','DEF','GHI'
PS > $array -match 'DEF'
DEF
PS > $array -match 'def'
DEF
PS > $array -match [regex]'def'
PS > $array -match [regex]'DEF'
DEF
```

What is actually going on, here? What is the [regex] doing, that results in case sensitivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[regex]'def'` is casting the string to a [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.aspx) object, which is case-sensitive by default. PowerShell regular expressions on the other hand are case-insensitive by default.

```
PS C:\> ('def').GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\> ([regex]'def').GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Regex                                    System.Object
```

Comment: Why is it `[regex]` and not `[Regex]`?

Comment: OK, it is a "[type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-7.1)" (alias for a .NET framework class). In this case, `regex` (lower case) is an alias for .NET class `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$array -match` calls are case-insensitive by default.

Adding the `[regex]` keyword initiates a regular expressions search, and regular expressions are by default case-sensitive. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have enough reputation to comment to add to @Ansgar Wiechers answer, I will answer here to also note if you want to ignore case when casting [regex] from .NET, you can prefix your pattern with (?i) which is a mode modifier (case insensitivity).  [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html) is a good resource where you can check out the available mode modifiers (there's a lot).

So, `PS > $array -match [regex]'(?i)def'` would return true.